# Que tengo mal en mi if en python

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo el presente ejercicio, y me arroja siempre la ultima pregunta ( Hoy descanso). No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, seguramente algo muy simple ( pero, eso cuando se encuentra la respuesta).

> Crea un programa que pregunte por teclado  si
> hay "chocolate" primero y si hay "harina" después .

```
chocolate = 0
harina=0

chocolate = input("Hay Chocolate?")
harina = input("Hay Harina?")


if chocolate == True:
    if harina == True:
        print("Cocinamos tarta")
    else:
        print("Haremos bombones")
else:
    if harina == True:
        print("Hornearemos pan")
    else:
        print("Hoy descanso")
```

> Imprime:
> Si ambos son ciertos imprimiremos "Cocinamos una tarta"
> Si solo es cierto "chocolate" imprimiremos "Haremos bombones"
> Si solo es cierto "harina" imprimiremos "Hornearemos pan"
> Si ninguna es cierta imprimiremos "Hoy descanso"

Comment: `chocolate` siempré será `True` pues cualquier cadena es un valor *truthy*, ¿que ingresas en el `input()`??

Comment: Estoy ingresando ceros y unos.Gracias, voy a modificar, pero no lo estaba tomando en cuenta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que está pasando es que estás comparando lo que introdujo el usuario con un booleano. La función `input()` te devuelve un `string`, y tu condición siempre dará `False` si comparas su valor con un booleano. Además, no necesitas definir las dos variables con 0 al principio. Para resolver esto, deberás comparar True como string

```py
chocolate = input("Hay Chocolate?").lower()
harina = input("Hay Harina?").lower()


if chocolate == "true":
    if harina == "true":
        print("Cocinamos tarta")
    else:
        print("Haremos bombones")
else:
    if harina == "true":
        print("Hornearemos pan")
    else:
        print("Hoy descanso")
```

Comment: el `if` depende de lo que ponga como input, se puede pensar fácilmente que debe ser `True` o `False` por la comparación que hace, pero con las variables inicializadas con `0` me confundió @_@. Como dato extra puedes convertir el texto a minúsculas y así evitamos un pequeño fallo o incompatibilidad por mayúsculas :D

Comment: @Christian Hecho, gracias por tu aporte ^^.

Comment: Estas mezclando "true" y "True".

Comment: Genial, hecho. Como estoy respondiendo con ceros y unos, en vez de lower, pase los nputs a enteros. Muchisimas gracias, No me voy a olvidar mas que las respuestas de textos son ceros o false, jajaja. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estas confundiendo los tipos de variables, la función '*input'* todo lo que recibe lo devuelve como string, es decir, un texto. Un texto no es lo mismo que un booleano (Variable que solo puede tomar dos valores, True o False), en lugar de lo que estas haciendo puedes hacer un menú por ejemplo:

```
print('Ingresa 1 para decir si, y cualquier otro numero para decir no')
```

Con esto puedes validar las respuestas mas fácilmente, ahora puedes validar las respuestas, y si son correctas harás lo que tienes planteado en el ejercicio:

Aqui pides las respuestas:

```
chocolate = int(input('Hay chocolate?'))
harina = int(input('Hay harina?'))
```

Aquí evalúas las respuestas:

```
# Una forma de resolverlo sería esta:
if chocolate == 1:      
    if harina == 1:
        print('Cocinamos tarta')
    else:
        print('Haremos bombones')
else:
    if harina == 1:
        print('Hornearemos pan')
    else:
        print('Hoy descansamos')
```

Esta solución es valida pero es bastante larga ya que ocupa muchas líneas de código; puedes optimizarla haciendo lo siguiente:

```
# la palabras 'and' esta diciendo que si ambas condiciones se cumplen harás los siguiente
if chocolate == 1 and harina == 1: 
    print('Cocinamos tarta')
else:
    if chocolate == 1:
        print('Haremos bombones')
    else:
        if harina == 1:
            print('Hornearemos pan')
        else:
            print('Hoy descansamos')
```

Pero incluso hay una forma mas corta de escribir esto:
Verás, la sentencia 'elif' es un condicional que se ejecuta cuando la sentencia anterior no se cumple, en pocas palabras, es un 'else' con un 'if' juntado en una sola palabra 'elif'.
Ejemplo:

```
if chocolate == 1 and harina == 1: # Esta es la condición inicial
    print("Cocinamos tarta")
elif chocolate == 1: # Si la condición anterior no se cumple evalúas esta
    print("Haremos bombones")
elif harina == 1: # Si la anterior tampoco se cumple evalúas esta
    print("Hornearemos pan")
else: # Si ninguna de las condiciones anterior se cumplió
    print("Hoy descanso")
```

Si lo miras desde el punto de visto organizado te darás cuenta que es igual a la primera solución pero escrita en menos palabras

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tambien puedes hacerlo sin utilizar booleanos:

```
chocolate = input("Hay Chocolate? ").lower()
harina = input("Hay Harina? ").lower()
if chocolate=='si' and harina == 'si':  print("Cocinamos tarta")
elif chocolate=='si' and harina == 'no':  print("Haremos bombones")
elif harina == 'si' and chocolate=='no':  print("Hornearemos pan")
else:  print("Hoy descanso")
```

Comment: recuerda que se recibe como entrada `0` y `1`